# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, port

I am having an issue with logging into phpMyAdmin.

I have simply install xampp.
when i launch the Xampp server it show me port error for 3306
so i have change the port from 3306 to 3307 
in my.ini file and 
config -> Service and Port Settings -> Mysql port Tab

[Service Setting of Xampp Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtZDE.png)

Then i was able to start SQL server

when i try to open PhpMyadmin it show me error like this
than i change in config.inc.php

[config.inc.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SX9P.png)

Now when i try to open PhpMyadmin it ask me for username and password

```
Username - root
Password - Null
```

it show me error like this
[Error while login in PhpMyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TbBN.png)

Please Help me to find an issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Posted in pastebin.com please check below link
https://pastebin.com/depf39JT

Comment: The link above has your question and my.cnf only.  Still need Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C1) last 400 lines of ERROR LOG after restart D) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, for server tuning analysis.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry but can you tell me where to find as i don't know  
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps,

and are you talking about mysql_error.log or Apache(error.log)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in the very early stages of using xampp and 
NO development has been completed;

Uninstall xampp and remove ALL the MySQL* programs, Shutdown/Restart Windows 10.

Reinstall xampp.  Verify functionality.

For additional assistance, view my Profile, Network profile, for contact information including my Skype ID and get in touch with me, please.